# Choose title- and file name at runtime

Tags: variables, cross-browser, runtime, autoit

I am trying to automate file upload in two browsers but the window name is "File Upload" in Firefox and "Open" in Chrome. I don't want to write two different scripts.

How to choose title- and file name at runtime to achieve cross browser compatibility? I use Selenium and testNG, AutoIt only for file upload.

Comment: Can you share the code Neha ?

Comment: In firefox:- ControlFocus("FIle upload","","Edit1")
ControlsetText("File Upload","","Edit1","C://file.xls")
ControlClick("FIle Upload","","Button1")
In chrome:-
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlsetText("Open","","Edit1","C://anotherfile.xls")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
The title changes on different browser so my test fails..I then want to write an autoiT script which accepts Title on runtime ..Also is there a way to provide the file name in run time as well???

Comment: @Neha Soni, there is no need to use AutoIt. Selenium supports file upload with `sendKeys` called on the `<input>` element.

Comment: I agree @florent  but developer has not given text entry option so i have to find a way out with other third party tolls

Comment: @Neha Soni, a text entry is not required, just the `<input>` element even if it's hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable based off the web browser being used, then use that variable. The code below should get you on the right track.

```
$FirefoxUpload = "File upload"
$ChromeUpload = "Open"

if WinExists($FirefoxUpload)
  $UploadWindow = $FirefoxUpload
elseif WinExists($ChromeUpload)
  $UploadWindow = $ChromeUpload
else
  $UploadWindow = ""
endif

if $UploadWindow <> ""
  ControlFocus($UploadWindow,"","Edit1")
  ControlsetText($UploadWindow,"","Edit1","C://file.xls")
  ControlClick($UploadWindow,"","Button1")
endif
```

Comment: Thank-you so much dale i think this might solve my issue ..Also can i make a run time variable for different files to be attached ??

Comment: Yes. If you want user to select files look at help on FileOpenDialog. If you have the list look at help on Arrays. Or maybe you have a list of files in a text file, then check out the FileOpen, FileRead, ... entries in AutoIt help.