# Selecting an element in a Jira dialogue (pop up) using Selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jira

I am working on `Jira` and writing a selenium `testcase` to attach an attachment from a `Jira` dialogue which pops up on a button click.

The attachment can be added by clicking a browse button where I am trying to use `sendKeys` to send the absolute path of the file to be attached.

Basically the same `css` segment is present in the `Jira` screen before the dialogue pops up and is also present on the dialogue with the same tag parameters.

The html of the dialogue is as below:

```html
<div class="jira-dialog-content">
  <form id="issue-workflow-transition" class="aui" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/jira/secure/CommentAssignIssue.jspa">
   <div class="form-body" style="max-height: 236px;">
    <fieldset class="group">
     <legend>
      <span>Attachment</span>
     </legend>
     <div class="field-group file-input-list long-field">
      <div class="issue-drop-zone -dui-type-parsed" data-upload-size="10.00 MB" data-upload-limit="10485760" duitype="dndattachment/dropzones/CreateIssueDropZone">
       <div class="issue-drop-zone__target"></div>
       <span class="issue-drop-zone__text">
        <span class="issue-drop-zone__drop-icon"> </span>
        Drop files to attach, or
        <button class="issue-drop-zone__button" type="button"> browse.</button>
        <input class="issue-drop-zone__file ignore-inline-attach" type="file" multiple="">
       </span>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="dnd-dropzone">
     </div>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

I want to get this element from this html using selenium and pass on the absolute path of the file.

```
<input class="issue-drop-zone__file ignore-inline-attach" type="file" multiple="">
```

I am not able to make this work. When I try this on the page using

```
driver.FindElement(By.className('issue-drop-zone__file'))
```

then I am able to attach the attachment.

But the same thing I am not able to achieve from the dialogue. Can someone give some pointers on how this can be done.

I also used :-

```
driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector('#issue-workflow-transition > div.form-body > fieldset > div > div > span > input'))
```

but `selenium` complains that

> the element was not found

Comment: No i am not clicking the input. Instead I am sending the absolute path of the file using sendKeys function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your tried `cssSelector` looks incorrect to locate `dropzone` upload file element in the dialog box, I have tested it using [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait until dialog present with `dropzone` upload file then perform `sendKeys()` into dialog `dropzone` element and it's working fine as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//Now click on create button to open dialog
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("create_link"))).click();

//now sendKeys on upload button
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("issue-drop-zone__file"))).sendKeys("you file to upload");
```

Comment: This certainly worked. I made some changes based on my needs and I was able to make it work. Thanks a ton @Saurabh Gaur

Answer (score 0):

sendingKeys to input dialog works always.
try to click the dialog and use third part software (like autoit\ coded ui ) to upload the file.
you can use the following autoit script:

```
$FirefoxUpload = "File upload"
$ChromeUpload = "Open"

if WinExists($FirefoxUpload)
  $UploadWindow = $FirefoxUpload
elseif WinExists($ChromeUpload)
  $UploadWindow = $ChromeUpload
else
  $UploadWindow = ""
endif

if $UploadWindow <> ""
  ControlFocus($UploadWindow,"","Edit1")
  ControlsetText($UploadWindow,"","Edit1","C://file.xls")
  Contro

lClick($UploadWindow,"","Button1")
endif
```

found in answer 
[How to automate upload file in different browser using single AutoIT script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234455/how-to-automate-upload-file-in-different-browser-using-single-autoit-script)